# Does gcc initializes auto variable to 0?

Tags: c

Why am i getting 0. I is an auto variable, so it should print some garbage value, right? I am using gcc compiler.

```
#include "stdio.h"
void main() {
int i;
printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Zero is a valid garbage value :)

Comment: There's no rule *against* an uninitialized variable having a value of 0. It's just not guaranteed.

Comment: I am getting 0 everytime i compile and run this program.

Comment: The compiler, or the run-time libraries, may be prefilling the stack with 0. Or it may be an artifact of the executable load process. Or it might be the leftover value from a stack variable in a setup routine called before `main()`. Still not illegal. Still not guaranteed.

Answer (score 5):

> Does gcc initializes auto variable to 0?

Yes and No!
Actually uninitialized auto variables get **indeterminate value** (either an unspecified value or a trap representation<sup>**1**</sup>).

Using such variables in a program invoke undefined behavior-- *behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
for which ANSI C International Standard imposes no requirements.* (C11:§3.4.3)

Once UB is invoked you may get either expected or unexpected result. Result may vary run to run of that program, compiler to compiler or even version to version of same compiler, even on temperature of your system!

---

<sub>**1**. An automatic variable can be initialized to a trap representation without causing undefined behavior, but the value of the variable cannot be used until a proper value is stored in it. (**C11: 6.2.6 Representations of types--Footnote 50**)</sub>

Comment: But i am getting 0 everytime. Not only for this program, for every program an auto variable is giving 0 instead of garbage value.

Comment: @AkashSinha it doesn't matter, just because you are getting 0 there everytime, doesn't mean you will get 0 everywhere everytime. If you don't initilize a value, it contains garbage, and that garbage may or may not be 0.

Comment: Zero or not zero, UB can and will cause nasal demons. That's for sure.

Answer (score 1):

No, I get random values with gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2.

```
ofd@ofd-pc:~$ gcc '/home/ofd/Destkop/test.c' 
ofd@ofd-pc:~$ '/home/ofd/Desktop/a.out' 
-1218415715
ofd@ofd-pc:~$ '/home/ofd/Desktop/a.out' 
-1218653283
ofd@ofd-pc:~$ '/home/ofd/Desktop/a.out' 
-1218845795
```

Comment: Shall I add this as a comment or is it OK as an answer?

Comment: You should also explain why is it happening?

Comment: @haccks I wish I knew how he got 0 :) I mean, we both use the same compiler.

Comment: @pmg Actually Terminal generates the path itself with single quotes when you drag&drop the file.

Comment: @pmg Lol. It's really practical.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared inside a function are uninitialized. One cannot predict what might show up if you print them out. in your example `main` is a function too. Hence it so happens that it is zero.

When you declare variable to be static or gloabally, the compiler will have them initialzed to zero.

Answer (score 0):

It has become standard security practice for freshly allocated memory to be cleared (usually to 0) before being handed over by the OS.  Don't want to be handing over memory that may have contained a password or private key!  So, there's no guarantee what you'll get since the compiler is not guaranteeing to initialize it either, but in modern days it will typically be a value that's consistent across a particular OS at least.